# ACPI: power off vs shutdown

Tags: linux, centos, kvm, qemu, acpi

I'm running a virtual machine with CentOS 7 guest. ACPI daemon is started.

When I shutdown the hypervisor, then guest operating system powers off. I can see in guest's syslog that it was notified that power button was pressed, but it does not stop all the services. Guest operating system just stops.

Is there a way for hypervisor to wait till all the services in the guest operating system are stopped?

Comment: depends on the hypervisor, I would say. Which one are you using?

Comment: You should definitively tell which virtualization software you are using, and how you shutdown the hypervisor.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I see this happening, it is because the administrator of the VM has not configured or started the services properly.

In RHEL/CentOS 6, unless the startup script created a service-specific flag file to indicate that the service was started, the shutdown procedure would skip shutting down that service because it would assume that the server had already been stopped, or not started in the first place. But this still allowed stopping and re-starting a service that was initially started at boot time any way the administrator wished.

With RHEL/CentOS 7, if you start a service using the `systemctl` command or the `service` compatibility wrapper, the service processes get placed in its own *control group* which is tracked by `systemd`. If you just run `/etc/init.d/name-of-service start` on the command line, this will not happen. Even if the service was initially started at boot time, if you stop and restart it manually, the service-specific control group will vanish as soon as it no longer has any living processes in it.

And when the system is shutting down, `systemd` will go through all the service-specific control groups, run the `ExecStop` actions on them, and wait until all the processes in that control group are dead or a timeout is reached. Any processes remaining in the "default" control group are assumed to be not associated with any particular service and simply killable, which may not be the correct way to stop processes started with `/etc/init.d/name-of-service start`.

So, in any system with `systemd`, using the proper command to start services (= with the `systemctl start <name>` or the compatibility wrapper `service <name> start`) is important in a new way.

Answer (score 1):

First off, are you sure that the guest didn't shut itself down after waiting long enough for services to stop?

I'm going to assume you're using libvirt to manage your qemu VMs. If you want to customize how long your local systemd gives libvirtd to shut down its guests, I believe you would define TimeoutStopSec in a systemd drop-in unit corresponding to libvirtd.service. See [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html) for more information about that.